# Replace comma by newline using django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am using django and python.

I am passing post from views and I am displaying destination as `{{post.destination}}` using django template. If the database value for destination is `"Shakespeare,Edison,Fleming"` I need to replace `','` by new line.

Anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one step solution for this.

What you can do is, in your view make a string replacing `','` with `'\n'` and use it in template to show as line breaks.

e.g.

in view:

```
 new_destination = post.destination.replate(',', '\n')
```

In template, use `linebreaksbr` filter which puts `<br/>` tag for each new line.

```
{{new_destination|linebreaksbr}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the comma by new line using filters/tags in template, however there's no  built-in one for this. You can write your custom tag, check the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/

However I think the more appropriate way is to complete the replace in your view function, and pass the processed value in context to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Django template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).
I think, it would be best for this.

Comment: There is all written there. You need to write tag function, like: `destinationNl(destination_str): return destination_str.replace(',', '<br />'), include this tag to template html and use it like django original template tags.

Comment: I tried this and it helped me. Thanks.@register.filter(name='line_break')
def line_break(value):
    return value.replace(',', ',\n')